# Are integration tests like that possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, integration, uitest

It seems that in Xcode there are two kinds of tests, UI-tests which test an app running in another process using Automation, and Unit tests, where small units of code are tested in isolation. I wonder if there's a middle ground somewhere...

For instance, if I run unit tests there's a full app launched in memory that I don't use, because I am instantiating the classes that I need for testing in my test case classes. (I only know it's there because I see it in the simulator window and because my test classes sometimes accidentally communicate with it using notification center.)

It would be nice though, if I could use this app for integration tests. They would be similar to UI-tests, but much faster, and I would be able to access the implementation. I could for instance do that in order to install mocks so I can simulate behaviour of remote endpoints and see what the effects of certain responses are from the view point of the user.

The question is: Is there a good (documented) way to start up an app with mocks in the XCTest context and find that middle ground between unit tests and UI-tests?

Answer (score 0):

funny thing, the other day we were also having this kind of problem. I'm not sure if this info might help you.

So the short answer to your specific question is that there is no written documentation in the apple docs(AFAIK) that specifically states how to make mock classes inside your tests but it doesn't necessarily mean you cant make one. There are a lot of ways on which you can make a mock up scenario to work with your code

manual way : making protocols/interfaces to be implemented by a working class and a mock class, overriding specific methods of working classes to somehow mock results, swizzling and etc.

3rd party way : notables (OCMock, Mockito)

in the case of objective c, there's a lot of 'em 3rd parties out there but with swift there are a few out there that are still in development because of the support that swift has with its runtime library (swift is yet to fully expose its runtime library)

here's a helpful link : https://academy.realm.io/posts/tryswift-veronica-ray-real-world-mocking-swift/ (great article)

Cheers